# How to convert markdown to rich text (rtf) in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: browser, text, convert, html

I want to convert text written in `Markdown` to `Rich Text` on Ubuntu 13.04. I could not find any solution on the web, except for one Mac OS X [script](http://brettterpstra.com/2013/03/08/new-in-the-markdown-service-tools-in-place-markdown-to-rtf/).

How can I do that on Ubuntu 13.04? Preferably in the browser.

P.S. I don't need it the other way, the text gets always written in `Markdown` and needs to get transformed to rich text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One alternative is http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/ which is in the repos,

```
sudo apt-get install pandoc
```

Then you can take your **markdown** file and convert it to **rtf**, or a variety of other formats with,

```
pandoc -s -f markdown -t rtf -o file.rtf file.txt
```

The `-s` switch is for standalone, so that it doesn't just create an **rtf** fragment. There are also a variety of other useful switches such as `-S` for smart quotes. I use it all the time to create **epub** and **pdf** files.

It would also be a good idea to check out the documentation on their site, since the **pandoc markdown** format supports several extensions.

Comment: Pandoc is probably the best utility for this kind of work, good answer

Comment: Buggy tool. Randomly misses line breaks, item blocks and titles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a two-step approach. Open your markdown file in ReText (available from the Software Center) and export in `.odt` format. Then open the `.odt` file in `LibreOffice Writer` which allows saving as `rtf`.

```
ReText is a text editor for Markdown and reStructuredText markup languages, written in Python.

Features:
* Full Markdown and reStructuredText support
* Markdown extensions support
* Supported export formats:
   - HTML
   - PDF
   - ODT (OpenDocument Text)
   - Webpages generation
* Tabs and Live preview
* CSS styles support
* Syntax highlighting
* Tags and symbols boxes for quick insert
* Page breaks support (for Markdown)
```